# retrieve json type data from posgres and store it in the hashmap

Tags: java, json, postgresql

I have json type columns in the table in DB.When I am retrieving using select query which gives me object of list containing the json data.Now when I am storing it into hashmap it's giving me exception --java.lang.ClassCastException: org.postgresql.util.PGobject cannot be cast to HashMap

Here is the code

```
private String getData(List inputList) {
    HashMap userInput=null;
    HashMap configInput=null;
    PGobject obj=null;

    try {
        HashMap map=new HashMap();
        map=(HashMap) inputList.get(0);
        userInput= (HashMap) map.get("user_input");
        configInput = (HashMap) map.get("config_map");
    } catch(Exception e) {

    }
}
```

where the inputList contaiins

```
[{user_input={"TYPE":"os","NAME":"linux.abc.com"}, config_map={"a":true,"b":"R","configHashMap":{"arg":"cpu"}}}]
```

My select query is-

```
select user_input,config_map from logTable where id= "abc";
```

How to solve this exception. I don't wand to cast it to string and then hashmap.

Comment: Why are you using raw types? Are you not using Java 5 or greater?

Answer (score 0):

It is simply not possible to cast a JSON value to a HashMap because there is no way to derive the actual types of the values. Implementing a function that derives Java datatypes from the JSON datatypes and creates nested HashMaps from a JSON object would contradict the Java object oriented philosophy.
If you want to create Java objects from JSON values (retrieved as Strings from the database), take a look at for example the [GSON library](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) from Google.